# how to use RemovedInNextVersionWarning?

Tags: python, django, libraries

I've written a library Django, I want to update it. But I need that to the people who use it say that this function will be removed in the future, how should I say this?

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(ModelAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.formfield_overrides = overrides
          warnings.filterwarnings(
              'ignore',
              'please use "ModelAdminJalaliMixin". example: class YourClass (admin.ModelAdmin, ModelAdminJalaliMixin):',
               RemovedInNextVersionWarning
          )
```

Comment: `RemovedInNextVersionWarning` means it is removed in the next version of Django. You would be better to create your own warning for your own library.

Comment: @Alasdair correct me if I am wrong but as I know RemovedInNextVersionWarning is just extended DeprecationWarning class to get filter capability by it inside django logging.

Comment: @iklinac yes, `RemovedInNextVersionWarning` is an alias for a subclass of `DeprecationWarning`. My point is that `RemovedInNextVersionWarning` specifically means that it will be removed in the next version of Django. This `ModelAdmin` class is going to be removed in a future version of @Arman's library, not in the next version of Django. Therefore he should create his own subclass of `DeprecationWarning`.

Comment: @Alasdair I definitely agree that he should create his own error class, just wanted to recap it

Comment: thank you @Alasdair and @iklinac. I finally decided to use the `print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInNextVersionWarning
import warnings     
warnings.warn('WarningString', RemovedInNextVersionWarning)
```

[warnings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) are python module, RemovedInNextVersionWarning is django class extended on [DeprecationWarning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.DeprecationWarning)